# Tkinter docs for Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to contribute to the tkinter docs. I was wondering where the official repository is for it? These are the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html
but I am not sure where the source code is.

Comment: see [`tkinter` GitHub repository](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/tkinter) for the source code, you can also contribute there, not so sure about making amendments to the official docs (there also really aren't any official docs)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html : is this not the official doc?

Comment: hard to tell, the closet to official, I would say, is to use `help(tkinter)` in code (after `import tkinter`), but if you want to contribute there [docs.python.org], you have to ask them, not here

Answer (score 2):

There is an ongoing effort and discussion on the [python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/) regarding updating the tkinter documentation.

You can register to join the discussion, and the effort here: [Improve Tkinter Documentation](https://bugs.python.org/issue42560)

Your help is needed and will be appreciated.