# How can I align image to center of heading in ttk.Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Tried to replace text heading by image heading in ttk.Treeview, but image always align right.
How can I align the image to center of heading ?

Here, image is a small blue box for demo only, most of time, the size of image always smaller than column size.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, ttk

root = Tk()

font = ('Courier New', 20)
headings = [f'Column {i}' for i in range(3)]
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=headings, show='headings', height=5)

im = Image.new("RGBA", (20, 20), "#0000ffff")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

for heading in headings:
    treeview.heading(heading, image=image, anchor='w')
    treeview.column(heading, width=200)

style = ttk.Style()
heading_name = "Treeview.Heading"
style.configure(heading_name, font=("Courier New", 40))
treeview.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

After add style layout, and set `('Treeheading.image', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''})`, the image aligned to top center, not on center in both of vertical and horizontal.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, ttk

root = Tk()

font = ('Courier New', 20)
headings = [f'Column {i}' for i in range(3)]
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=headings, show='headings', height=5)

im = Image.new("RGBA", (20, 20), "#0000ffff")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

for heading in headings:
    treeview.heading(heading, image=image, anchor='w')
    treeview.column(heading, width=200)

style = ttk.Style()
heading_name = "Treeview.Heading"

style.layout(heading_name,
             [('Treeheading.cell', {'sticky': 'nswe'}),
              ('Treeheading.border', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                  ('Treeheading.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                      ('Treeheading.image', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''}),
                      ('Treeheading.text', {'sticky': 'we'})
                      ]})
                  ]})
              ])

style.configure(heading_name, font=("Courier New", 40))
treeview.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

[Update]
Here's the result of my script after I got solution here.
Heading not text, but rotated image.

[image]

Comment: In `ttk.Style` you can edit the layout for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments you can use ttk.Style for this. An exampel can be found below:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, ttk

root = Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)

font = ('Courier New', 20)
headings = [f'Column {i}' for i in range(3)]
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=headings, show='headings', height=5,
                        style='my.Treeview')

im = Image.new("RGBA", (20, 20), "#0000ffff")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

for heading in headings:
    treeview.heading(heading, image=image, anchor='w')
    treeview.column(heading, width=200)

treeview.pack()

style.layout('my.Treeview.Heading',
             [('Treeheading.cell', {'sticky': 'nswe'}),
              ('Treeheading.border', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                  ('Treeheading.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                      ('Treeheading.image', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': '','expand':True}),
                      ('Treeheading.text', {'sticky': 'we'})
                      ]})
                  ]})
              ])

root.mainloop()
```

I just changed `('Treeheading.image', {'side': 'right', 'sticky': ''}),`

Comment: It looks like only align to center of horizontal, but stay top in vertical. Sorry about it, the height of heading is still greater than height of image.

Comment: @JasonYang see if this line does the job for you `('Treeheading.image', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': '','expand':True})`

Comment: Yes, it work ! I didn't find the option `expand` in pdf for tkinter 8.5. Thank you  !!!

Comment: @JasonYang I needed to do some research too. I use [this site for](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_style.html#M20)

Comment: It's for tcl/tk, not everything shown in tkinter document.

Comment: @JasonYang yes, tkinters documention lacks a little bit of details, see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70505064/13629335). But if I compare it to other modules I use its pretty good and has a broad helping community.

Comment: So I still need to check something in tcl/tk website, anyway, thank you again !