# How to align image cells in Tkinter Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

It seems that `Tkinter Treeview` doesn't support image alignment for default column `#0`, of course I've tested on some texts it worked, yet image. I've tried various alignment methods, and even when forcing alignment using spaces in the `text` attribute, it still doesn't align properly. Does anyone know how to address this issue?

```
self.device_tree.heading("#0", text="Ping", anchor=tk.CENTER)
self.device_tree.column("#0", anchor=tk.CENTER)

# Use spaces to force alignment
        self.device_tree.insert("", 'end', text='   ', values=(device_name, ip_address), image=status_image, tags=('device',))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I align image to center of heading in ttk.Treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518713/how-can-i-align-image-to-center-of-heading-in-ttk-treeview)